# AI Fire Script - Error - GetComponent<ScriptName>().functionName()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i tried to create ai fire script.
First of all script create random two numbers for shooting position.And check the position is there army object or floor object.
If there is army object apply damage until destroy it but if there is floor object just flag it was shot, because i want to ai script doesn't shoot floor object second time.

there is a problem which is NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object 
the error line  GetComponent().startEnemyFire();

Here ai fire script

```
public class EnemyFire : MonoBehaviour {

    public int min;
    public int max;

    public static int enemyDamage=2;
    public static bool empty;


    void Start(){

        empty=true;

    }

    public void startEnemyFire(){

        if(empty==true){
            Debug.Log("create Position");
            createPosition();


        }
        if(empty==false){

            shot();

        }
    }


    public void createPosition(){

        min=Random.Range(0,5);
        max=Random.Range(0,5);

        shot();

    }

    void shot(){

        Vector2 pos=new Vector3(min,max,0);

        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast ((pos), -Vector2.up);
        if(hit.collider != null)
        {

            GameObject target = hit.collider.gameObject;
            if(target.tag=="army"){
                target.GetComponent<playerArmyMove>().Damaged(enemyDamage);
                empty=false;
                Debug.Log("army shoted");
            }

            if(target.tag=="floor"){


                target.GetComponent<FloorScript>().changeSprite(enemyDamage);

                Debug.Log("floor shoted");

            }

        }

    }
    }
```

and here floor script

```
public class FloorScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public  Sprite damageSprite;
    public  bool shot =false;

    public int hp=1;

    public void changeSprite( int value){

        if(shot ==true){

            GetComponent<EnemyFire>().createPosition(); //Error is here

        }

        if(shot ==false){

        hp-=value;
        if(hp <= 0)
        {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = damageSprite;
                shot=true;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Is there any suggestion how can i fixed it or should i create an array for saving shot position and check the array if position already created?

Comment: You should not use `GetComponent<>` in code that is executed frequently. You should create a field and initialize it in `Start()` method. If this component is used by other components make it as property with private setter.

Comment: Thanks your advice , i will work on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach `EnemyFire` script to the-same GameObject the `FloorScript`  script is attached to in the Editor.